# Export SWF to Image/PDF in PHP

Tags: php, fusioncharts

I'm using FusionCharts Free for a page, and I'm trying to export the graph, to image or/and PDF. The Trial Version have this option, and is very useful, but the Free version does not have this function. The code to make a graph is very simple:

```
<?php
     echo renderChartHTML("FCF_Column3D.swf", "Data/Data.xml", "", "myFirst", 600, 300);
?>
```

Is there any library, script or something to export this code in PDF or JPG?
Thanks

Comment: Screen capture -> save as JPEG/PDF?

Comment: Yes, something like that... Is possible to capture just the part of the screen where the graph is?

Comment: Since you're using a PHP page on a website, check the extensions directory for your browser for screenshot tools; Firefox and Chrome both have several that can crop for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not available in FusionCharts FREE.

However, the commercial version provides a lots of options.

1. Using chart's [own library](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/exporting-image/ECOverview.html)
2. Using ASP.NET Image Saver Assembly (unable to get a link for this at this moment)
3. Using http://fcimg.org/